# API/Library for Flex/Bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I was building a compiler and am using Flex and Bison. However building the project gets complicated. Is there an API or library available for them, which we can import and use with the C or C++ code?
 Other similar tools will work too, not just Flex/Bison.

Comment: An API or library to do what, exactly? If you're talking about building the project, then all standard build tools (automake, cmake, etc.) have some kind of built-in flex/bison support, although you may have to customise it to get what you want.

Comment: @rici Not for building. For using functionality of flex/bison. Like using them as functions instead of having to define the grammar in a different file and having to compile it separately.

Comment: Ah. No, the whole point of flex and bison is to generate code. (This is similar to the reason that C is a compiler, rather than being implemented through some kind of `eval_C` function :-) ). But if you use the build tools available to you, building a project which uses bison and flex is not at all difficult.

Comment: @rici Yeah that's what I have been doing. Just wanted to know it was available. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If there is some specific pain point which is complicating your life, please feel free to ask a more specific question. Questions like this one (asking for extermal libraries or other off-site resources) are outside of SO's scope, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you are searching for a software, there is the Software Recommendation Stack Exchange https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ .